# Display a message on test success below the test case

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

Hello I wanted to ask a question concerning the **teardown** method of the selenium and Nunit testing tools.

Now I have a certain test and I'm using the latest Nunit framework which unfortunately made something unacceptable in tests, which is I cannot use **`Assert.pass`** method inside a **teardown** function. I'm using `Assert.pass` actually to display a certain message below the test case in Visual studio. Is there a way to display this message without the `Assert.pass` function?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can you not use `Console` or `Assert`?

Comment: It's a test class with Nunit and Assert can't be used inside the teardown method since version 3 .. Console isn't working, i don't even have a terminal when i run the test case to see the output.

Comment: You need to be more specific about where you want the message written.

Comment: i need it to appear below the test case in VS where assert.pass displays the message normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the NUnit adapter currently works, the only way to cause a message to appear below the tree is through a failing assertion or by using Assert.Ignore, Assert.Pass, etc.

As NUnit currently works, you can't use any Assertions, even Assert.Pass, in teardown without causing an error. That's because the test has already finished at that time and it's result is set.

Two workarounds:

1. Put Assert.Pass in every test.
2. Create an Action Attribute to run code after each test. I haven't tried this and I'm not looking at the code right now, so no guarantees on this one. :-)

Comment: Thanks so much charlie , i would possibly go for the first workaround but the problem is the project is huge and there's a lot of test cases so i have to call Assert.pass in each test. Anyways, would you help me in answering this question since you're aware of Nunit ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854137/selenium-grid-with-nunit-3-0-implemented-in-c-sharp

Answer (score -1):

Use `Console.WriteLine("")` If you want to print it into the output window.

Comment: Thanks for your help but console.writeline isn't what i want in this application.